# Link to different React Component with parameters on a separate page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am new to react

I have a react component customer and I have link in there to link to address component. I want to pass in props of a boolean that it is a city address. How can I do that in React?

Code

```
 return (
<>
<Grid>Customer Details </Grid>
<Link to="/address" cityAddress={true}>Address</Link>
</>
)
```

Address Component

```
const Address =  ((props) => {
 const {
    cityAddress
  } = props;

return (<> {cityaddress ? City Address Details : Address Details} </>)
Address.propTypes = {
  cityAddress: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default Address;
```

Comment: You can't do this via props, you'll need to use something like context API, so it's shared across all pages

Comment: @Jayce444 Are you saying I cannot move between pages in react by passing the parameters?

Comment: @LearnAspNet you pass the value on query param like this '/address/:cityAddress'

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya I am trying to get to another component. That does not have any parameter, it has a prop of cityAddress

Comment: No you can't do it via props. You can do it via parameters as others have suggested, or you'll  have to use a centralised store approach. You aren't actually rendering the component in place where the `Link` is, so you aren't able to pass props to it

Comment: @Jayce444 I have updated my question with Address component. It does not have a query parameter. If I pass the query parameter of cityAddress, will that work?

Comment: @LearnAspNet no because you're passing the `cityAddress` prop to the `Link` component, **not** the `Address` component

Comment: @Jayce444 Is there a way to use Router Component and pass a prop of CityAddress. There has to be a way to do this?

Comment: You can pass one directly in the `Route` component, if that's what you mean: `<Route path='/address/ render={() => <Address cityAddress={true} /> } />`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use url param like this.

```
<Link to=“/address?city=true”>Address</Link>
```

I think you can look at the url param at the transition destination and differentiate the display.
What do you think?